# How to check if folder is empty or have folder file use shell-script?

Tags: linux, shell

i have a question

i try some function like

> DIR=/path/tmp/
>
> if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then

and

> if [ -f "$DIR" ]; then

but only check /path/tmp this path

how can i do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `ls -A` for this:

```
if [ "$(ls -A "$DIR" 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]; then
    # The directory is empty
fi
```

`-A` shows all hidden files and directories except the `.` and `..` that are always there, so it will be blank in an empty directory and non-blank in a directory with any files or subdirectories.

The `2> /dev/null` throws away any error messages `ls` may print (note that checking a non-existant directory will yield a false positive, but you said you already checked that it existed). Checking a directory where you do not have read access also yields a false positive.

Comment: This could be unfavorable if the directory contains huge amount of (long name) entries. Also, "$DIR" needs quotes. To account for that - `... [ "$(ls -A "$DIR" 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)" == "" ] ...`

Comment: @Zrin: It feels very strange to put quotes in quotes without any escaping or anything, but I tested it and you're absolutely right (at least, my test with a directory name with a space failed with my original and worked with your change). Thanks! Does the `| head -n 1` actually help anything, though? `ls` will still produce the full list won't it?

Comment: @t-j-crowder `| head -n 1` will take the first line from `ls`, output it and then cut the input - i.e. it says "that's enough!" There is also a nice solution with `read` instead of `head` - try `| read` and check exit code.

Comment: @Zrin: I know what `head` does. But what does it achieve here? `ls` is still going to do all the work of reading the large number of names, regardless.

Comment: You're right that `ls -A` will read the whole directory into memory and sort it before outputing the first line. The advantage of piping through `head` is that bash wouldn't need to read all of it in (thinking e.g. of large maildirs). The disadvantage is that it's starting another process. Perhaps `ls -AU` starts the output right away? Perhaps `if ! ls -AU | read _; then echo 'it's empty'; fi`

Answer (score 20):

#### From the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) #4 -- *How can I check whether a directory is empty or not?*

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=(*)
(( ${#files[*]} )) || echo directory is empty
shopt -u nullglob dotglob
```

This small script fills the array `files` with each file found in the path expansion `*`.  It then checks to see the size of the array and if it's 0 it prints 'directory is empty'. This will work with hidden files thanks to the use of `dotglob`.

#### Note

Answers which ask to parse `ls` is in general a bad idea and poor form.  To understand why, read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: +1 for a non-`ls` solution, though note that my answer *doesn't* parse the output of `ls`. It just checks whether it has any. :-)

Comment: if i want to use it in php systen(); it can use?

Comment: another question  files can use path ?

Comment: This would be unfavorable if the directory contains huge amount of entries (with long names) because it loads it all into memory just to check if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ -z "$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 0 -empty)" ] || echo "$DIR is empty!"
```

`find` has predicate `-empty` which tests if a directory or file is empty, so it will list the directory only if it's empty. `-z` tests if output of find is empty. If it is, then the directory contains entries, if it isn't then it's empty.

In other code words:

```
[ -n "$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 0 -empty)" ] && echo "$DIR is empty!"
```

---

Another quite nice one:

```
if ! ls -AU "$DIR" | read _; then
    echo "$DIR is empty!"
fi
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 1):

why don't use `ls -v` ? so will print out empty if no file such as

```
if $(ls -v $DIR)
```

Comment: Why `-v` ("natural sort of (version) numbers within text")? Speed?

Comment: Also, this doesn't check for hidden files.

Comment: This will produce an error if the directory is not empty. If you do `if ls -v $DIR` there's no error but it's always true. You have to do `if [ "$(ls -v "$DIR")" ]` or `if [[ $(ls -v "$DIR") ]]`. Use `!` to invert the logic, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This tells me if the directory is empty or if it's not, the number of files it contains.

```
directory="/path/tmp"
number_of_files=$(ls -A $directory | wc -l)

if [ "$number_of_files" == "0" ]; then
    echo "directory $directory is empty"
else
    echo "directory $directory contains $number_of_files files"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this using only shell built-ins (it should work for all shells I have worked with):

```
if test "`echo /tmp/testdir/* /tmp/testdir/.?*`" = \
    "/tmp/testdir/* /tmp/testdir/.."; then
  [...]
fi
```

We do not check /tmp/testdir/.* because that will expand to /tmp/testdir/. /tmp/testdir/.. for an empty folder.

Another built-in-only variant:

```
for i in /tmp/testdir/* /tmp/testdir/.?*; do
    test -e $i || break
    [...]
    break
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`rmdir "$DIR"`

If `$?` is 1, the directory isn't empty. If 0, it was empty and it gets removed.

You may recreate it if you don't intend to remove it: `mkdir "$DIR"`

Comment: He didn't say he wanted to remove the directory. Removing it just to find out if it's empty is a very bad idea.

Comment: Because you're removing the directory, and he didn't say he wanted to do that. Maybe there's another process that's about to write to the directory. Maybe he doesn't have rights to remove it. The point is, it's a destructive operation and one isn't required.

Comment: To be fair, I think this answer is still useful. Maybe someone's looking at this question with a use-case where a destructive try-removing-and-then-re-create thing is a non-issue, and there is a *simplicity* to this approach which other approaches just don't have.