# How to check a non-empty directory on a remote machine in single command

Tags: linux, shell

In shell script,

how to check whether a directory is non-empty on a remote machine?

Regards

Comment: What shell are you using? And what version of linux?

Comment: normal [ "$(ls -A dir)" ] don't work at ssh remote command method.

Answer (score 4):

`find PATH_TO_REMOTE_DIRECTORY -maxdepth 0 -not -empty`

`-maxdepth 0` will make sure you only check the directory, and not all subdirectories recursively.

`-not -empty` is straightforward.

This will print the path if not empty, and will print nothing if empty.

And, of course, run it via `ssh`.

Comment: find PATH_TO_REMOTE_DIRECTORY -maxdepth 0 -not -empty -exec \; can execute command at remote machine

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to execute the command mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253698/how-to-check-if-folder-is-empty-or-have-folder-file-use-shell-script) via `ssh`:

`if [ "$(ssh user@host ls -A /dir/ 2>/dev/null)" == "" ]; then echo "empty"; else echo "not empty"; fi`

Note: non-existing directories will also be reported as empty.

Comment: if logic should be at remote machine.