# How to check if all folder and sub-folder are not empty?

Tags: ssh

I use a ssh command to copy files from a serveur to another :

```
scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no login@sourceserver:/sourcefolder/* /destinationfolder
```

After that, I want to check if the folder "destinationfolder" and all its sub-folder are not empty.

I find this question ([How to check a non-empty directory on a remote machine in single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426392)) that looks like what I want.
I tried this :

```
find destinationfolder -empty
```

It seems to work but if I have an file that is empty, it returns the address of this file.

What can I do to check if folder are not empty but don't check if files are empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer here :
http://ss64.com/bash/find.html

I need the option "-type d" to filter only directories.

So the ssh command line is :

```
find destinationfolder -empty -type d
```